# Unable to change the value of "i" th index of an array in javascript using a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a code where user will see a list of all issues and it has two buttons:

1. Close the issue
2. Delete the issue

So, while calling delete function, it is not changing the status of the issue.

The close() function is changing the status of the "i" th issue and calling fetchIssues() function but it is not changing the status.

**Close Issue:**

```
function close(i) {

    var issues=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    issues[i].status="Close";
    fetchissues();

}
```

**Fetch Issues:**

```
function fetchIssues () {

    var issues=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    var I;
    for(i=0;i<issues.length;i++) {

        var id=issues[i].id;
        var description=issues[i].description;
        var severity=issues[i].severity;
        var assignto=issues[i].assignto;
        var status=issues[i].status;
        document.getElementById('issuesList').innerHTML += 
            '<div class="well">'+
                '<h5> Issue ID : '+ id + '</h5>' + 
                '<h4><span class="label label-info">'+ status +'</span></h4>'+
                '<h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paste"></span>'+"     "+  description + '</h3>'+
                '<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>'+'     '+ severity+'         '+'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>'+'     '+ assignto + '</p>'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="close(i)">Close</button>'+'  '+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete(i)">Delete</button>'+
            '</div>';

    }

}
```

**Save Issue:**

```
function saveIssue(e) {

    var id=chance.guid()
    var description = document.getElementById("issueDescInput").value;
    var severity = document.getElementById("issueSeverityInput").value;
    var assignto = document.getElementById("issueAssignedToInput").value;
    var status="Open";
    var summarized = {
        id,
        description,
        severity,
        assignto,
        status
    }

    var final=JSON.stringify(summarized);
    if(localStorage.getItem('issues')===null) {

        var issues=[];
        issues.push(summarized);
        var finalissues=JSON.stringify(issues);
        localStorage.setItem('issues', finalissues);
        alert("saved");

    } else {

        var issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
        issues.push(summarized);
        var finalissues=JSON.stringify(issues);
        localStorage.setItem('issues', finalissues);
        alert("saved");

    }
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchIssues();

}
```

Comment: `close` gets the list of issues from localStorage, sets the status of one of them, then calls `fetchIssues`. `fetchIssues` gets the list of issues from localStorage. Note that the list of issues in localStorage was never changed between the two retrievals.

Comment: I got your point and i saved updated issues to the localStorage. But , still the status is not changing. And, I am getting an error :- ReferenceError: i is not defined

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere. That's because you're using strings for HTML and `onclick="close(i)"` doesn't know what `i` is. You need `onclick="close(' + i + ')"`

Comment: Sir, it is still not working. You can look at my code here.   "https://codepen.io/adishrtv/pen/gOaVvxE"

Comment: Okay, so the code in that CodePen is different from the code shown here; that's a problem. The answer given by pcarrara works for the code given here. I think that any further difficulties you have applying it to your code should be asked in a new question.

Comment: Thank you. It is working now.

Answer (score 2):

In the following function:

```
function close(i) {
   var issues=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
   issues[i].status="Close";
   fetchissues();
}
```

You have to save it to localstorage first, you don't simply set the issue[i].status="Close" and expect the localstorage version to be updated, you have to set it with:

```
localStorage.setItem("issues", JSON.stringify(issues))
```

So, your close function should be:

```
function close(i) {
   var issues=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
   issues[i].status="Close";
   localStorage.setItem("issues", JSON.stringify(issues));
   fetchissues();
}
```

There is also the problem pointed by @heretic-monkey:

> That's because you're using strings for HTML and onclick="close(i)"
>   doesn't know what i is. You need onclick="close(' + i + ')"

Comment: Sorry, i am a beginner in javascript. Can I ask why my code is still not working?

Comment: The "issues" variable is a copy of what is set in the localStorage, it is not a reference to it, so, if you set the property of any of the objects in the array it will not relate to any of the values in the localStorage. The localStorage browser feature is not reactive, it does not detect changes made to variable derived from it.

Comment: So, is there any way by which I can change the status in localStorage and display it using fetchIssues() funtion.

Comment: Yeah, there is, if you look at answer, i've updated my answer to better explain what I mean. Before calling "fetchissues()", save it to localStorage.

Comment: @pcarrara If you want to fold in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62136046/unable-to-change-the-value-of-i-th-index-of-an-array-in-javascript-using-a-fun?noredirect=1#comment109895097_62136046) into your answer, I think that will solve the issue.